# On EC2: sudo pm2 ls command not found, but pm2 ls without sudo is ok

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, sudo, pm2, amazon-linux

Problem: When I run `"pm2 ls"` under ec2-user, it runs perfectly.

When I run "pm2 ls" after `sudo -i`, it gives -bash: pm2: command not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for safety reasons, sudo typically runs under a different environment. for example, an administrator could configure sudo to use a secure PATH rather than inheriting the caller's PATH.

you have a few options:

1. preserve the caller's PATH using `--preserve-env`, e.g. `sudo -E "PATH=$PATH" env`.
2. modify the sudoers policy to set PATH to include pm2's parent directory.
3. move pm2 to a directory that's already in the secure path.

lastly, you can reconsider if pm2 really needs root permissions.